# Tableau For Loop a String

Tags: json, excel, vba, excel-formula, tableau-api

I have the following table I am trying to transform the json data into multiple calculated fields but I am stuck as I have multiple firstname in the same column.  Please see the example below of what Im trying to achieve. Thank You for your help.

| School | StudentJson |
| --- | --- |
| Middle School | [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"doe","firstname""Patrick","lastname":"mahomes","firstname":"steve","lastname":"segal"}] |
| High School | [{"firstname":"tom","lastname":"brady","firstname""jason","lastname":"fred"}] |

Final Result

| School | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Middle School | John | doe |
| Middle School | Patrick | mahomes |
| Middle School | steve | doe |
| High School | Tom | segal |
| High School | Jason | Fred |
| High School | John | doe |

I have tried using a forloop and split but it didnt work

Comment: *I have tried using a forloop and split but it didnt work*  So what was the try, what was the result?

Comment: Your json input looks invalid

Answer (score 0):

In the case of

```json
[
   {
      "firstname":"tom",
      "lastname":"brady",
      "firstname":"jason",
      "lastname":"fred"
   }
]
```

You have all the paramaters under the same object. Does changing your json to be

```json
[
   {
      "firstname":"tom",
      "lastname":"brady"
   },
   {
      "firstname": "jason",
      "lastname":"fred"
   }
]
```

Fix your issue?